# Fixing iOS 15 UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The top of my nav bar is showing gray/slightly translucent during transitions. This just started in iOS 15 I've tried fixing using the following code but no luck:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    
    open override func awakeFromNib(){
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            let apr = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            self.isTranslucent = false
            apr.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            apr.backgroundColor = .white
            self.scrollEdgeAppearance = apr
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting the navigationBar standardAppearance property:

```
self.standardAppearance = apr
```